# How to fix buildpack error when deploying flask to Heroku?

Tags: python, flask, heroku

Followed all the steps to deploy Flask application. The app works fine on the localhost with no issues or errors. I added requirments.txt  runtime.txt and Procfile. I runtime.txt I typed python "python-3.9.0". Procfile:  "web: gunicorn app:app". And requiements.txt has these packages:

```
    click==7.1.2
Flask==1.1.2
flask-heroku==0.1.9
gunicorn==20.0.4
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
Werkzeug==1.0.1
```

When I push it to heroku this is the error I get:

[image]

Documentation on Heroku website is not really helpful. I don't have any clue what specifically can cause issues.

Comment: What is your flask application file name?

Comment: It's not detecting that you want to use the python buildpack. But it should since you specified a `runtime.txt` and `requirements.txt`. Are you developing locally on the master branch as well?

Comment: have you named your requirements file as `requirements.txt`?
what command are you running to push it into the Heroku?